# Como adicionar includes por expressão em repository pattern C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, include, repository

Estou criando um RepositoryBase (Repository Pattern) com EntityFramework Asp.Net Core, e nele estou criando um método Where, onde passo uma expressão where da entidade. Até aqui o método funciona perfeitamente, mas neste mesmo método gostaria de passar uma expressão de includes para ser adicionado antes de ser realizado o SQL.

Exemplo:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public RepositoryBase()
    {
        SetDbContext();
    }

    public void SetDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = new AberturaDeContasContextFactory().CreateDbContext();
    }

    public DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public string MessageError = "Erro ao {0}. Source: {1}, Exception: {2} ";

    public ICollection<TEntity> Where<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>[] properties)
        where TProperty : EntityBase
    {
        try
        {
            var source = DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(where);

            if (!properties.IsObjectNull())
            {
                foreach (var prop in properties)
                {
                    source.Include(prop);
                }
            }
            return source.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format(MessageError, "Pesquisar todos com where", ex.Source, ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

> Ao realizar o SQL, o include não esta funcionando

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Repository.Repositories.RepositoryBase<Cliente> repositorio = new Repository.Repositories.RepositoryBase<Cliente>();

        var a = repositorio.Where<Documento>(x => x.ClienteId == 1, doc => doc.Documento).ToList();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faço da seguinte forma:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> SelectIncludes(Func<TEntity, bool> where, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();

    IEnumerable<TEntity> resultado = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));


    if (where != null)
        resultado = resultado.Where(where);

    return resultado.ToList();
}
```

Para chama-lo:

```
MinhaClasse minhaClasse = _meuRepositorio.SelectIncludes(p=> p.Id == 1, i=> i.ClasseRelacionadaUm, i=> i.ClasseRelacionadaDois).FirstOrDefault();
```

<sub>Pode ser que você precise fazer alguns ajustes pela forma como está implementando o *pattern*.</sub>

Comment: Só uma duvida @Barbetta, se eu colocar a clausula `Where` antes dos includes ele não funciona, realmente só funciona quando é coloco antes os includes?

Comment: @NicolaBogar, Sim, os `includes` devem vir antes. Dará *exception* caso tenha algum `where` que acesse propriedade do `include`, e caso não tenha não fará os `joins`